# Jmeter give timestamp value in exponential format. How to convert it to number?

Tags: jmeter

I used the `${__time())` function to convert the current time into a timestamp value in seconds.
The result I got was formatted like `1.543425678e9` instead of `1543425678`.
My API doesn't accept this format. Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

[example of setup function and store as variable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gce4J.png)

result in debug postprocessor:
time=1557263114733

Can you describe more detail about how you are using this function?  Where are you seeing the output in the incorrect format?